# Choosing Machine Learning Algorithm and tool

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a binary classification problem i.e need to classify my data into two categories. For every entity have extracted 5 features.

Now I want to decide on which algorithm I should use.
Also I wanted to know what will be the most convenient language which has library that maybe already supports this algorithm and I can implement it.

I am just a beginner at ML. So it might be a very stupid question. But any help will be great.

Thanks and Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to machine learning, you should take a modest approach to learning it. Don't expect to dive in with the "best" algorithm (it doesn't exist). Instead, find some good resources on machine learning, there's lots of free information on the Internet, such as Wikipedia or lecture notes. Alternatively if you require more structure, there are books available too. So with this in mind...

1) Choose a simple classification algorithm to start with. It doesn't have to be the 'best', but it has to be a simple one you can get to grips with. There's no point try to use a more sophisticated approach, because if it produces unexpected output you won't be able to figure out why. Perhaps start with a simple clustering algorithm, such as [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

2) Choose your language / environment to be whatever you are familiar with. Basic machine learning algorithms are available in many places. Mathematicians might be familiar with Matlab or R. Programmers can find libraries in Python, C, Java, Fortran... If you aren't familiar with any statistical packages and are new to programming, perhaps this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335063/whats-the-easiest-way-to-learn-programming

If you are not new to machine learning and already familiar with several approaches, I suggest checking out this question:
[When to choose which machine learning classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595176/when-to-choose-which-machine-learning-classifier)

Answer (score 2):

For solving a simple classification problem, I would suggest using **logistic regression**. It is  simple to understand and implement. There are much more sophisticated algorithms you could experiment with, such as **Support vector machines**, **Neural networks** etc. However, keep in mind that often in machine learning, it is not the algorithm you choose to use, as it is important to have a good data set, with carefully selected features.

There is also the question of using a classification or clustering algorithm. If you have a data set that is already labeled, I would suggest classification. However, if your data set is **not** labeled, the classification algorithms will not work, and you would have to use  clustering. **K-means** is a simple, yet widely used and efficient solution.

As far as the language/tools/environment/tools are concerned, I wold suggest Octave, R or Matlab if you don't have a solid programming background. If you do, try finding a good library in the language you are most fluent in. I can suggest a good, open source machine learning library for java - ([Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)).

Finally, I recommend [this](http://jan2012.ml-class.org/) Stanford online course on machine learning. It is free, suitable for beginners, and it doesn't require any background in any other field of science or engineering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to machine learning , you can check some machine learning algorithms in Stanford online Machine learning class(http://www.ml-class.org/). The class is very practical and you can learn some basic classification algorithms(e.g.logistic regression , SVM , Neural networks).And some classification exercise assignments(in octave/matlab) were also provided. And there were some practical methods to develop a classification system.  It may help you.