# What classification model should I use? New to machine learning. Recommendation needed

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

### the goal:

Hey guys, I'm trying to create a classification model in Python to predict when a bike-share station will have too much relative inflow or outflow per hour.

### what we're workin with:

The first 5 rows of my dataframe (over 200,000 rows in all) look like this, and I've assigned values 0, 1, 2 in the 'flux' column - 0 if no significant action, 1 if too much inflow, 2 if too much outflow.

[image]

And I'm thinking of using the station_name (over 300 stations), hour of day, and day of week as the predictor variables to classify 'flux'.

### the model choice:

What should I go with? Naive Bayes? KNN? Random Forest? anything else that would be a good fit? GDMs? SVMs?

fyi: the baseline prediction of always 0 is pretty high at 92.8%. unfortunately the accuracy of logistic regression and decision tree is right on par w that and doesn't improve it much. and KNN just takes forever....

Recommendations from those more experienced with machine learning in dealing with a classification question like this?

Comment: I think you should use the  `sqrt(abs(level_of_the_tides + distance_from_timesquare- number_of_days_to_fullmoon)/Math.PI)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley already ran it. good accuracy, but ROC leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: It seems that your data is unbalanced, so you cannot evaluate the model simply by accuracy.

Comment: There are tips for this in answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595176/when-to-choose-which-machine-learning-classifier, http://blog.echen.me/2011/04/27/choosing-a-machine-learning-classifier/  and more deeply at http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/choosing-what-kind-of-classifier-to-use-1.html.  It is difficult to predict in advance what model will work best and possibly a combination of models is better than any single one as was the case for the winner of the Netflix challenge.

Comment: @yangjie Could you elaborate on what else you could use to evaluate? Also, I'm trying to lower thresholds to make my model more balanced (baseline predicting accuracy 75%, no luck doing much better w basic models so far).

Answer (score 5):

The Azure machine learning team has [an article on how to choose algorithms](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-algorithm-choice/) which could help even if you aren't using AzureML.  From that article:

> **How large is your training data?** If your training set is small, and
>   you're going to train a supervised classifier, then machine learning
>   theory says you should stick to a classifier with high bias/low
>   variance, such as Naive Bayes. These have an advantage over low
>   bias/high variance classifiers such as kNN since the latter tends to
>   overfit. But low bias/high variance classifiers are more appropriate
>   if you have a larger training set because they have a smaller
>   asymptotic error - in these cases a high bias classifier isn't
>   powerful enough to provide an accurate model. There are theoretical
>   and empirical results that indicate that Naive Bayes does well in such
>   circumstances. But note that having better data and good features
>   usually can give you a greater advantage than having a better
>   algorithm. Also, if you have a very large dataset classification
>   performance may not be affected as much by the algorithm you use, so
>   in that case it's better to choose your algorithm based on such things
>   as its scalability, speed, or ease of use.
>
> **Do you need to train incrementally or in a batched mode?** If you have a
>   lot of data, or your data is updated frequently, you probably want to
>   use Bayesian algorithms that update well. Both neural nets and SVMs
>   need to work on the training data in batch mode.
>
> **Is your data exclusively categorical or exclusively numeric or a
>   mixture of both kinds?** Bayesian works best with categorical/binomial
>   data. Decision trees can't predict numerical values.
>
> **Do you or your audience need to understand how the classifier works?**
>   Bayesian or decision trees are more easily explained. It's much harder
>   to see or explain how neural networks and SVMs classify data.
>
> **How fast does your classification need to be generated?** Decision trees
>   can be slow when the tree is complex. SVMs, on the other hand,
>   classify more quickly since they only need to determine which side of
>   the "line" your data is on.
>
> **How much complexity does the problem present or require?** Neural nets
>   and SVMs can handle complex non-linear classification.

Now, regarding your comment about "fyi: the baseline prediction of always 0 is pretty high at 92.8%": there are anomaly detection algorithms - meaning that the classification is highly unbalanced, with one classification being an "anomaly" that occurs very rarely, like credit card fraud detection (true fraud is hopefully a very small percentage of your total dataset).  In Azure Machine Learning, we use one-class support vector machine (SVM) and PCA-based anomaly detection algorithms.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just use anything different from average accuracy for model evaluation in case of such unbalanced data: precision/recall/f1/confusion matrix:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics

Try different models and choose best according to chosen metrics on test set.