# Is Machine Learning the relationship between input & output

Tags: machine-learning

According to an article I read [here](https://www.academia.edu/19609256/Machine_Learning), Machine Learning is to do with teaching a machine how to do certain tasks through 'learning' input/output relations.

What is a more accurate definition of machine learning?

Comment: kind of correct? Yes, probably. A useful definition? Probably not.

Comment: All of computer science is basically a relationship between input and output.

Comment: The idea of ML is to determine a function `h : X -> Y`. In other terms, given old input and output, come up with a general function that can predict new output from new input. Even simpler, learning a rule then applying it rather than simply applying the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Machine Learning is to do with teaching a machine how to do certain tasks through input/output relations. Is this kind of correct?

The short answer is yes, *kind of*. Read on.

*Definition of Machine Learning*

To understand what Machine Learning is let's first define the term `Learning`. The often quoted definition by Tom M. Mitchell (1) is as follows:

> A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to
>   some class of tasks T and performance measure P if its performance at
>   tasks in T, as measured by P, improves with experience E

*Meaning?*

This sounds quite formal, however it just says computers learn from experience that they are presented with in terms of data. The data to enable learning exists relative to a specific task and consists of several parameters:

- *T*, a task to accomplish, e.g. predict housing price predictions
- *E*, some value of experience, e.g. prices observed
- *P*, some value of performance, e.g. how many prices are predicted

*Example: Housing prices*

Once a program has learnt from these inputs, it can take a *new, previously unseen* experience and from that predict, in our example, the specific housing price. The housing price might be strongly correlated to say location, age and size of house or apartment, and the luxury of its interiors.

*What is the result of a learning algorithm?*

In its simplest form then a machine learning algorithm for housing prices might implement a [multi-variate regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) analysis. It takes as input a body of data that relates real, *observed* prices to the four *features* location, age, size, luxury. The process of learning produces a regression model that in essence assigns a weight to each feature, of the form

```
y^ = w_location * location + w_age * age + w_size * size + w_luxury * luxury
```

That is, the weights `w_*` are *learned* from the input data, `y^` is the predicted price. The learning is considered successful once the formula is able to successfully predict housing prices based on a list of features alone. Usually a prediction is considered successful if it falls within a certain bound (%-range) of the real price.

Note that the definition of *successful* very much depends on the kind of task that the program must learn, however the result needs to be substantially better than a pure random guess (that is, the ratio of correct results needs to be statistically significant).

*Is there more to it?*

Yes, a lot. Some pointers can be found in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). If you are keen to get into the subject, professor [Andrew Ng's Standford lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzxYlbK2c7E) is quite famous, although there are many more courses if you look for it. Pick the one that best suits your interests.

*References*

(1): Mitchell, T. (1997). Machine Learning, McGraw Hill. ISBN 0-07-042807-7, p.2. as referenced by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Machine_learning&oldid=698513779)

Comment: Thats excellent, thank you so much. Just as a side note when it comes to algorithms are there algos which are exclusively for particular data types i.e nominal, oridinal, categorical, discrete?,

Comment: IMHO there is no good general answer - it depends on the size of the dataset, whether you want to understand the choices the model makes, if the order (in ordinal) matters for your application, do you run batch or online updates, etc. Ultimately you need to cross-validate different models to really know what works best for your application. Here's another question with [some pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595176/when-to-choose-which-machine-learning-classifier). btw, interestingly enough the latter is not put on hold, ah _stackoverflow misteries_... ;-)